# Multidemencional array in symfony twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Sorry for a beginner question but can't understand how to use a multidimensional array into twig, I'm new into Symfony2
my array is a:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => name
        [description] => description
    )

[submenu] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 6
                [name] => name
                [description] => description
            )

     )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => name2
        [description] => description2
    )
)
```

how i can the display in twig to get this result:

`name
   submenu[name] 
  name2`

Answer (score 0):

First of all;

Is it more than 2 levels? Or just 2 level?

If it is just 2 levels, you don't need to write a function that repeats itself.

So;

```
{% for key, value in array %}
    {% if key['submenu'] is defined and key['submenu'] is not empty %}
        {% for second_level_item in key['submenu'] %}
            Do something.
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If not;

You have to define a function that repeat itself (recursive) so you can reach multi levels.

Comment: Okay, that must be enough. But check for variables. It may be not key['submenu']. As i said, check variables (key, value) for which one has submenu in it.

Comment: hmm return me a empty string

Comment: How can i tell you here what must return? I have told you "how to do it yourself". Don't wait to get full solution of your problem from me. I'm helping you here. Just think of it.

Comment: {% for key, value in menu %}
        {% if key['submenu'] is defined and key['submenu'] is not empty %}
            {% for second_level_item in key['submenu'] %}
                {{ dump(second_level_item) }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

Comment: I have already told you to check the key and value variables. Dump key and value first to see which variable holds what.